# Android WebView sync cookies on older apis

Tags: java, android, cookies, android-webview

I am using CookieSyncManager to sync cookies. I followed the guide from [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html). Created instance in oncreate, stopped syncing in onPause, resumed in onResume. Additionally I fire

```
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

at the end of onPageFinished.

Since API21 I got a deprecated warning and according to the Android Documentation, we should use

```
CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
```

only now to fire a synchronisation.

I tried already

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
else CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

but it gives me an error of having API15 as minimum.

I do not like the idea of ignoring a deprecation but what to do with API15?

#### Edit:

From comment (not sure if I understood it right):

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
  
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) flushCookies();
  else syncCookies();
}

@TargetApi(21) //add this
private void flushCookies() {

  CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
}

private void syncCookies() {

  CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
}
```

Solves the lint hint I thougt it was an error.

Comment: 2 choices: first: don't care about deprecation use old, second: `if(getDeviceAPI()>=21) {use_new_API} else {use_old_API}` ... I would recomend 2nd

Comment: Sorry I tried that already. Forgot to mention and added to question.

Comment: ah, verify error ... then move `CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();` and  `CookieManager.getInstance().flush();` to 2 diefferent methods ... and call those methods instead ... dalvik verify classes on methods level (in API > 4 ...in API 4 on class level ...)

Comment: Not sure If I understand you but see edit. Same error: Call requires API21. Whetere Version A nor B

Comment: no, no ... `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) flushCookies() else syncCookies()` **edit:** Version A should works ... **edit2** it is not an error ... it is lint hint ... add annotation to `flushCookies`: `@TargetApi(21)` to get rid of it

Comment: Yes that solved the "error". But I still got the deprecated warning.

Comment: it doesn't matter as the code will run on "devices which this was not deprecated" ... add `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` to `syncCookies()` or just leave it

Comment: Ok thank you. Would you mind adding your solution as post so I can accept it?

Comment: have no time, writing the android's app :) ... you can always do it by yourself and just give a credits (like "based on Selvin's comment") :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on Selvin's comment:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) flushCookies();
  else CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
}

@TargetApi(21)
private void flushCookies() {

  CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
}
```

did the trick. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do it by different way:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void loadCookies() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
    } else {
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    }
}
```

Call this method in your onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
This code looks much clean and you shall not see your method to looks like deprecated.